# elements not styling properly to the right responsive bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, styling

a little brief about my code, i have a code that takes data from an array, map over them and then display cards like this:

i made the code so they stick to the right side using justify content:flex-end and its working fine but if i removed one element from the data this happens:

so as you can see they are not justified to the right anymore how can i make it responsive in a way that no matter how many data i have it will always be flex-end ?

code.js:

```
      const measurment = [
    { title: "Last Blood Pressure", value: "90/60",unit:"mmhg",subValue:"85 BPM",date:"05/14/2020 04:12",style:{color:'yellow'}},
    { title: "Last Body Weight", value: "154",unit:"lb",subValue:"13% Fat",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    { title: "Last SpO2", value: "98",unit:"%",subValue:"85 BPM",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    { title: "Last Glucose", value: "200",unit:"mg/dl",subValue:"",date:"05/14/2020 04:12",style:{color:'red'}}
]
const style = {
  width: "auto",
  height:"auto",
}
return(
<div style={{justifyContent:'flex-end'}} className="container">
      <div className="row">
      {measurment.map(measurment => {
          return (
            <div style={style} className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <Card
                style={measurment.style}
                title={measurment.title}
                value={measurment.value}
                unit = {measurment.unit}
                subValue={measurment.subValue}
                date={measurment.date}
              />
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
</div>
</div>
)}
```

Comment: how do you remove an element for measurment?

Comment: @buzatto i edited it the code and added the measurement data, i can for example remove a line from it

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the `flex-end` css to the `.row`, not to the `.container`.

the `.row` div is a block, so it will be 100% width so aligning it left or right won't change a thing.

Here is an example : https://codepen.io/GuillaumeGautier/pen/MWKKXaO

Also, if you're using Boostrap 4, you can simplify your card classes :

```
className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
```

becoming

```
className="col-md-3 col-lg-3"
```

defaut size is `col-12`